# Prove that A is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $A_{3x3}$ , and $Ax = 0$, $Ax = x$, $Ax = -x$ all have non trivial solutions. How can I prove that $A$ is diagonalizable?

As a start I know that $A$ is not invertible (concluded from $Ax = 0$ has a non trivial solution), the determinant of $A$ is zero. But what does the other information give me?

Comment: what criterion do you usually use to show that a matrix is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three distinct eigenvalues in a $3\times 3$ matrix.  That means that you have three linearly independent eigenvectors in $\Bbb R^3$. In that basis $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: So what is $P$ and what is $D$?

Comment: @UFCInsider $P$ has as columns the linearly independent eigenvectors of your choice, while $D$ has the corresponding eigenvalues along the diagonal, in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming A is defined over a field F with characteristic different from 2.

The conditions imply that A has eigenvalues 0, 1 and -1, respectively.
Different eigenvalues implies that the corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent.
Since A is 3x3, this means that these eigenvectors form a basis of the vector space F^3.
Since there is a basis of eigenvectors, A is diagonalizable.

In particular, A is similar to diag(0,1,-1).

Comment: So what is $P$ and what is $D$?

Answer (score 0):

If eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_r$ correspond  to *distinct* eigenvalues $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_r$, the set $\bigl\{v_1,\dots, v_r\bigr\}$  is linearly independent.

Hence, if you have $n$ distinct eigenvalues for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, representing an endomorphism of the space $K^n$ ($K$ denotes the base field),  this matrix is diagonalisable to a  matrix $D=\operatorname{Diag}(\alpha_1, \dots,\alpha_n) $ in a basis of $n$ eigenvectors.

Comment: So what is $P$ and what is $D$?

Comment: I've added what $D$ is. What do you denote $P$?

Comment: $D = P^{-1} \cdot A \cdot P$

Comment: Oh! The change of basis matrix. Well, its columns are the coordinates of the eigenvectors  in the original basis.